# How can I use content.scrollTo() for ion-scroll in ionic2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I try to scroll to a fixed position, for example scrollTo(500, 20). Let's say that you are on a device, which has got a width of 300 pixel. The scroll target is now out of the screen scope, you have to scroll to the right.

I solved this by doing the following:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-scroll scrollX="true" style="width:100%; height:100%; white-space: nowrap; ">
        <div style="width:1000px; ">
            [box1] [box2] [box3] [...]
        </div>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Up to here everything is fine. The problem starts if i want to jump 500 pixel to the right by pressing a button for example. Swiping to the right works. I know that there is a function to do this for `<ion-content>`:

```
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
[...]
this.content.scrollTo(500, 500, 500);
```

This unfortunately doesn't work in my case. I think the problem is that the content is related to the device size so the scrollTo() method does not take affect for `<ion-scoll>`. How can I use the scrollTo() method for `<ion-scroll>` instead of `<ion-content>`?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: not sure if this is the cause.. but `ion-scroll` generally needs  specific dimensions .. `%` doesnt work generally

Comment: in my case it is working well. I can scroll to the right and there is a scroll bar which is showing the scrollable area is probably 1000px wide. My problem is that ion-content fits to the screen dimensions and ion-scroll doesn't react to content.scrollTo(), because content has a width of 300 pixel and ion-scroll a width of 1000px.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I use the scrollTo() method for `<ion-scroll>` instead of
>   `<ion-content>`?

I'm still working on how to animate the scroll, but at least this may be considered as a solution for your scenario. Please take a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z2Ci1EXGjDlRdNRxy4mK?p=preview).

Since we can't use the`ion-content` for scrolling, I though about getting the instance of the Scroll, then accessing the inner html scroll element, and then using the [element.scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) property to scroll on that element:

> The element.scrollLeft property gets or sets the number of pixels that
>   an element's content is scrolled to the left.

So in the component code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild('scroll') scroll: any;

    constructor() {}

    public backToStart(): void {
      this.scroll.scrollElement.scrollLeft = 0;
    }

    public scrollToRight(): void {
      this.scroll.scrollElement.scrollLeft = 500;
    }

}
```

And in the view:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-scroll #scroll scrollX="true" style="width:100%; height:150px; white-space: nowrap;">
        <div  style="width:1000px;">
            <div style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid red;"></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid blue;"></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid green;"></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid grey;"></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid brown;"></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid yellow;"></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid orange;"></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid pink;"></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid violet;"></div>
        </div>
    </ion-scroll>

    <button (click)="backToStart()" ion-button text-only>Go to start</button>
    <button (click)="scrollToRight()" ion-button text-only>Scroll to right!</button>
</ion-content>
```

By doing `this.scroll.scrollElement.scrollLeft = 500;`, **we can scroll the content of the ion-scroll 500px to the right**. We can then go back to the start again by doing `this.scroll.scrollElement.scrollLeft = 0;`.

Comment: very nice answer, thank you! Unfortunately I get an error message: "Cannot set property 'scrollLeft' of undefined". If i write console.log(this.scroll) i get this: _scrollContent: ElementRef, nativeElement: div.scroll-content. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Hmm, maybe we're using different versions of Ionic. Instead of `this.scroll.scrollElement.scrollLeft = 500;` try with `this.scroll. nativeElement.scrollLeft = 500;`

Comment: i found it out, it is this.scroll._scrollContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)

Comment: Scroll is not smooth in this case. Is there content.scrollTo(x, y, delay) kinda thing for ion-scroll?

Comment: Great answer! I created an animation for smooth scrolling without use of any js library https://gist.github.com/sgotre/e070ef5cce1c778a6380d4c139047e13

Comment: i am using my ion-scroll inside ngFor and the above code `this.scroll.scrollElement.scrollLeft = 500;` is working for the first object only is there any solution

Comment: hi, can i give that number '500' pixels into some of the percentage

Answer (score 6):

By content scrolling

```
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
  this.content.scrollTo
```

By id #scroll

```
@ViewChild('scroll') scroll: any;  
this.scroll.scrollElement.scrollLeft = 500;
```

This above method is working fine for top bottom scrolling but in the case of horizontal/scrollX not working so by below code i resolve my solution   may hope it will helpful for you.

**TypeScript**

```
scrollmain(elementId, index) {
   console.info('elementId', elementId)
   var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
   el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-scroll #scroll scrollX="true" style="width:100%;white-space: 
          nowrap; height: 60px">
    <ion-segment *ngIf="mcqdata" color="appmaincolor">
        <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let mcq of mcqdata; let i=index;" [id]="mcq.ques_id" value="{{mcq.ques_id}}" (ionSelect)="scrollmain(mcq.ques_id,i)"
            [ngClass]="{'active': selectedIdx == i}">
            <strong>Queastion{{i+1}}</strong>
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
</ion-scroll>
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answers above, this will handle smooth scrolling.

Name the scroll element in your .html

```
<ion-scroll #scroll>
```

Import the scroll.

```
import { Scroll } from 'ionic-angular';
```

Reference the scroller in the .ts

```
@ViewChild('scroll') scroll: any;
```

Add this code where its needed:

```
this.scroll._scrollContent.nativeElement.scrollTo({ left: 0, top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get the dimensions of the element that you want to scroll to first? Assign an id to your ion-scroll in html file, then you can [use this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638003/anchorscroll-in-ionic-2-scroll-to-element-with-id):

```
scrollToElement(id) { 
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    // scrollLeft as 0px, scrollTop as "topBound"px, move in 800 milliseconds
    this.content.scrollTo(0, rect.top, 800);
}
```

From [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect): 
The returned value of getBoundingClientRect left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, height properties describing the border-box in pixels. Properties other than width and height are relative to the top-left of the viewport.

Looking at your code, I don't think you need ion-scroll, you should be able to just assign an id to your div and get the result you want.

Comment: hi. Thanks for you answer. My problem isn't based on finding the right position of the element i would like to scroll to. I can write this.content.scrollTo(500, 0, 800); directly but nothing happens. My problem is that ion-content fits to the screen dimensions and ion-scroll doesn't react to content.scrollTo(), because content has a width of 300 pixel and ion-scroll a width of 1000px. If I remove ion-scroll, i cannot scroll to the right. I tried a lot to make content scrolling. But everything didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't work when you remove ion scroll? Can you scroll manually in that case?

Comment: no i couldn't. Every solution I found uses ion-scroll. The main problem of ion-content was that i couldn't scroll to the right. I think ion-content is not made for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `this.content.scrollTo(...)` with `this.content._scrollContent.nativeElement.scrollTo(...)`