# Double click in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, click, double-click

I am trying to run out the (dbclick) event for Ionic3, but there is no way to make it run correctly ( it does nothing).

Is actually to somebody work this? Or Do we have to create it by ourselves with timeouts, etc...?

I've been searching for a while and it seems this option don't exist.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

you can look  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099796/how-can-i-use-content-scrollto-for-ion-scroll-in-ionic2?newreg=a841f04a20ed4d25bfb3ecc8c5664317)!

```
scrollmain(elementId, index) {
   console.info('elementId', elementId)
   var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
   el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
```