# Set horizontal scroll position - Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to change the scroll position of an `ion-scroll` element but don't getting.. this is what I have tried:

**ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

 @ViewChild("scroller", { read: ElementRef })
  private scroller: ElementRef;
```

**html**

```
 <ion-scroll #scroller scrollX="true" style="height: 21px; white-space: nowrap">
  <div>... </div>
 </ion-scroll>
```

**This works**

```
  this.scroller.nativeElement.style.background = "blue";
```

**This doesn't work**

```
  this.scroller.nativeElement.scrollLeft = this.scroller.nativeElement.scrollWidth;
```

Comment: Did you try solution from the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099796/how-can-i-use-content-scrollto-for-ion-scroll-in-ionic2